# What is the double sum of:

Tags: summation

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{ \sin[ka(m-n)]}{(m-n)} , m \neq n $

where $k$ and $a$ are constants.

How to treat this double sum?

Comment: Do you see why you don't need separate constants $k$ and $a$ but can replace their product by simply $b$?

Comment: Yes I can see it, but still can´t achieve to the solution.

Comment: So as a courtesy to the community, simplify your equations so we're not presented with irrelevant material.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the fact that $$\frac{\sin[(m-n)ka]}{m-n} = \frac 1 2\int_{-ka}^{ka}e^{i(m-n)t}dt$$

Comment: Could you please check my answer?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is what i got.
If there is any error, let me know, please.

Comment: Use msthjax please